# ConnectionError: Failed to connect to <SQLServerDB> - connect EACCES <SQLServerDB>

Tags: sql-server, node.js, azure

I am trying to connect to a SQL server DB using the config from Azure Cloud:

```
       var config = {
              user: UserName,
              password: Password,
              server: Server IP,
              dialect:'mssql',
              options: {database: DBName}
          };
    sql.connect(config, function (err) {
//Code
}
```

The Code is in node.js and it was running fine in my remote desktop. But after i hosted it in Azure Cloud i keep running in to this error

> > ConnectionError: Failed to connect to {SQLServerDB} - connect EACCES
> >     {SQLServerDB} at Connection.tedious.once.err (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious.js:216:17)
> >         at Connection.g (events.js:291:16)
> >         at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
> >         at Connection.emit (events.js:188:7)
> >         at Connection.socketError (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1004:14)
> >         at D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:869:25
> >         at Socket.onError (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\tedious\lib\connector.js:49:9)
> >         at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
> >         at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
> >         at emitErrorNT (net.js:1276:8)   code: 'ESOCKET',   originalError:     { ConnectionError: Failed to connect to {SQLServerDB}
> >     - connect EACCES {SQLServerDB} at ConnectionError (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\tedious\lib\errors.js:12:12)
> >            at Connection.socketError (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1004:30)
> >            at D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:869:25
> >            at Socket.onError (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\tedious\lib\connector.js:49:9)
> >            at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
> >            at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
> >            at emitErrorNT (net.js:1276:8)
> >            at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
> >            at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)
> >          message: 'Failed to connect to {SQLServerDB}- connect EACCES  {SQLServerDB},
> >          code: 'ESOCKET' },   name: 'ConnectionError' }

SQL Server is using default port and TCP/IP is enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to error information, it indicates that it can't connect to your SQL server. 
I assume that you are using local SQL server.

If it is that case, webapp can't connect the local SQL server by default. You could use [Hybrid connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections) to make sure that you  can connect to the local SQL server. I also recommand that you could use [Azure SQL database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/) to replace local SQL server.

Comment: Thank you @Tom Sun

Comment: I am using database which is located on azure and node application is also located on same server. Still getting the same error as @JeminJose mentioned above.
I am new on azure. please help.